# Copy elements of 1 list into other list using C language

Tags: c

I have created a program that gets 10 values in a list and then stores it in another list later on and then displays. Now the thing is code is very long. Can you please tell me how to use for loop instead of declaring and using these many variables and then copying them in again list.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

int marksList1 = 0;
int marksList2 = 0;
int marksList3 = 0;
int marksList4 = 0;
int marksList5 = 0;
int marksList6 = 0;
int marksList7 = 0;
int marksList8 = 0;
int marksList9 = 0;
int marksList10 = 0;

int correctedList1 = 0;
int correctedList2 = 0;
int correctedList3 = 0;
int correctedList4 = 0;
int correctedList5 = 0;
int correctedList6 = 0;
int correctedList7 = 0;
int correctedList8 = 0;
int correctedList9 = 0;
int correctedList10 = 0;

printf("Enter Marks for Students: ");

scanf("%d", &marksList1);
scanf("%d", &marksList2);
scanf("%d", &marksList3);
scanf("%d", &marksList4);
scanf("%d", &marksList5);
scanf("%d", &marksList6);
scanf("%d", &marksList7);
scanf("%d", &marksList8);
scanf("%d", &marksList9);
scanf("%d", &marksList10);

correctedList1 = marksList1;
correctedList2 = marksList2;
correctedList3 = marksList3;
correctedList4 = marksList4;
correctedList5 = marksList5;
correctedList6 = marksList6;
correctedList7 = marksList7;
correctedList8 = marksList8;
correctedList9 = marksList9;
correctedList10 = marksList10;

printf("\n");

printf("CorrectedList1: correctedList1);
printf("CorrectedList1: correctedList1);
printf("CorrectedList1: correctedList1);
printf("CorrectedList1: correctedList1);
printf("CorrectedList1: correctedList1);
printf("CorrectedList1: correctedList1);
printf("CorrectedList1: correctedList1);
printf("CorrectedList1: correctedList1);
printf("CorrectedList1: correctedList1);
printf("CorrectedList1: correctedList1);
}
```

Comment: Here's an interesting trick, too. Maybe not too relevant here, but imagine you had to have three arrays. It would become more useful. `x = y = 12;` This resolves right-to-left, so first y becomes 12, then x is set equal to y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should have declared a list for markedList and correctedList like this:

```
int i, marksList[10] = {0};
int correctedList[10] = {0};
```

I will just show you how to create a for loop for only first list and then hope you can do the same for 2nd list and for printing the correctedList. Here is the for-loop for markedList:

```
for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    printf("Enter Marks for Student %d: ", i+1 );
    scanf("%d", &marksList[i]);
}
```